# Trying to redirect to a url in Next JS API router giving me a cors issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js, shopify

I am trying to redirect to a shopify url from a next JS api route but it is giving me a cors issue, I was able to do it client side but I need to do it server side since I have tokens.

I have tried the following to no avail

```
// Next.js API route support: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction
const { checkHmacValidity } = require("shopify-hmac-validation");

import Cors from "cors";
import initMiddleware from "../../lib/init-middleware";

// Initialize the cors middleware
const cors = initMiddleware(
  // You can read more about the available options here: https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuration-options
  Cors({
    // Only allow requests with GET, POST and OPTIONS
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"],
  })
);

export default async (req, res) => {
  await cors(req, res);

  console.log("req.body", req.body);

  const test = checkHmacValidity(process.env.SHOPIFY_SECRET, req.body.query);

  if (test) {
    const nonce = req.body.query.timestamp;

    res.redirect(
      `https://website.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id=${process.env.SHOPIFY_TOKEN}&scope=write_orders,read_customers&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/shopifyConfirm&state=${nonce}&grant_options[]=per-user`
    );
  }
};
```

middle ware

```
// Helper method to wait for a middleware to execute before continuing
// And to throw an error when an error happens in a middleware
export default function initMiddleware(middleware) {
  return (req, res) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      middleware(req, res, (result) => {
        if (result instanceof Error) {
          return reject(result);
        }
        return resolve(result);
      });
    });
}
```

axios request

```
axios({
      method: "post",
      headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
      url: "/api/shopifyEntry",
      data: {
        query: Router.query,
        nonce: nonce,
      },
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        // handle success
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, [Router]);
```

Comment: Don't respond to API calls with HTTP redirects. You will need to perform the navigation in the front-end so instead try responding with the URL

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense, thanks